# How is it possible to finish drawing the missing polygons in a grid with reference to the nearest vertices?

Tags: mesh

Can I somehow finish drawing exactly the same polygons in this zone as above ? Perhaps it is possible to somehow pull the edges by snapping to neighboring vertices ?

[image: Text]

Answer (score 1):

Go into *Edge Select* mode. Make sure *Snapping* is set to *Vertex* and *Snap With* > *Closest*, also enable *Auto Merge Vertices*.

[image: snapping options]

Then select the edge at the first row you want to fill up. Extrude it with <kbd>E</kbd> and move it down to the next row. If you don't have the *Snap* tool enabled (the magnet symbol) you can hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to temporarily enable snapping. Move the edge so that it snaps to the corner vertex of the next row. Confirm with left-click.

[image: extrude + snap]

Now extend the edge selection to the edges of the next row and repeat the extrusion and snapping process. Repeat this until all rows are filled up. The *Auto Merge Vertices* option should ensure that all duplicate vertices get merged during the extrusions.

[image: extrude + snap again]

Answer (score 0):

*Snap* - *Vertex*

*Snap With* - *Closest*

Tap  <kbd>E</kbd>

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), otherwise it may be converted to a comment.